# Why the mapping.xml and configuration.xml has to be outside the pojo package?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have just started to learn the Hibernate and found this in various online sites : `mapping.xml` and `config.xml` has to be defined outside the pojo package?

Why is that so?

Also what's the difference between JPA and Hibernate. I searched through web and According to me hibernate is just one of the implementation of JPA. Could u correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have just started to learn the Hibernate and found this in various online sites : mapping.xml and config.xml has to be defined outside the pojo package?

You can put `xml` configurations whenever you want. For an example

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildsessionFactory();
```

Configure a session factory from the default `hibernate.cfg.xml`. It is the same as

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildsessionFactory();
```

So why `hibernate.cfg.xml` should be in the root of the source folder (or in the `resources` folder) in this situation?

Hibernate tries to load `hibernate.cfg.xml` via class loader

```
    InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream( "hibernate.cfg.xml" );
```

if you specify just a name without a path (`"hibernate.cfg.xml"`) a class loader will try to find a resource in the root of the compiled sources folder — `bin` or `build` folder, or the `classes` folder for `war`. The `resources` folder after build is copied (for an example, by Maven) in the root of the build or `classes` folder.

if you specify

```
new Configuration()
        .configure("/some/pojo/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildsessionFactory();
```

A class loader will try to find a resource in the `some.pojo` package. In this situation Hibernate removes the leading `/`, because of for a loading via a class loader the leading `/` is incorrect. So you can use a code below too

```
new Configuration()
        .configure("some/pojo/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildsessionFactory();
```

The same rule for other paths to the `xml` resources.

> Also what's the difference between JPA and Hibernate. I searched through web and According to me hibernate is just one of the implementation of JPA. Could u correct me.

Yes, Hibernate is an implementation of JPA. But one thing more. If you use the `SessionFactory` you can think that you don't use `JPA`. But in the same time you  use JPA annotations (`@OneToMany` for an example).  When you use `EntityManager` — you use `JPA` exactly.