# ClassNotFoundException in Hibernate Web App Example

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I got error in hibernate web application FileNotFoundException for which i have given right file path

Below is my error log

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:118)
    at eql.com.dao.EmployeeDAO.addEmployee(EmployeeDAO.java:16)
    at eql.com.controller.EmployeeControllerServlet.doPost(EmployeeControllerServlet.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Below is my method which will call in servlet

```
public void addEmployee(String FirstName,String LastName,String email,String Password,String phone, String City) {
    try {
     Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
     SessionFactory sessionFactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory();
     Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
     Transaction transaction =session.beginTransaction();
     Employee em=new Employee();
     em.setFirstname(FirstName);
     em.setLastname(LastName);
     em.setEmailid(email);
     em.setPassword(Password);
     em.setMobile(phone);
     em.setCity(City);
     session.save(em);
     transaction.commit();
     System.out.println("\n\n Details Added");
    }
    catch(HibernateException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         System.out.println("error");
    }
```

Hibernate-configuration is as follow

```html
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">sql123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create </property>
        <mapping resource="src/main/resources/Employee-hbn.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

POJO-Mapping is as follows:

```html
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="eql.com.model.Employee" table="Employee123">
        <id column="ID" name="empid" type="java.lang.Integer" />
        <property column="FirstName" name="firstname" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="LastName" name="lastname" type="string" />
        <property column="Email" name="emailid" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="Password" name="password" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="Phone" name="mobile" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="City" name="city" type="java.lang.String" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my project structure:
[image]

Can anybody would have solution? help me out...

Comment: Your stack trace does *not* show any `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: I got error in addEmployee() method that does not find the hibernate.cfg.xml file.....

Comment: `got error in addEmployee()` fine&dandy - care to show *that*? What is "the `ClassNotFound`-stack-trace" good for? How is hibernate to know `hibernate.cfg.xml` resides in *…resources*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you should understand:
the path to the `hibernate.cfg.xml` should be determined not using a source tree (like in the picture, provided by you), but by the some rules for class path resources.

[Why the mapping.xml and configuration.xml has to be outside the pojo package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002488/why-the-mapping-xml-and-configuration-xml-has-to-be-outside-the-pojo-package/36006946#36006946)

So for your source tree:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
        .configure("src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

this should be changed too

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
```

and this

```
 <mapping resource="src/main/resources/Employee-hbn.xml" />
```

should be

```
 <mapping resource="Employee-hbn.xml" />
```

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

You have this error because of you don't have a jar with `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException` class in the class path. Other reasons can be: there are two jars with different versions, or jar is loaded by different classloaders (unlikely).

So the main reason is you specified incorrect paths to the resources and after that `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException` is generated, but there is not the class for this exception in the class path. So the original error is hidden by  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`.

Comment: I did as above then i got hibernate.properties not found

Comment: @JyotiJadhav So you have fixed an error from your question. This is other error. And `hibernate.properties` file is not necessary for Hibernate. Maybe better to create other question with that error (with stack trace). Also, please, provide a Hibernate version.

Comment: Here is my other question    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461301/hibernate-properties-does-not-found-in-maven-project-using-hibernate