# hibernate.properties does not found in maven project using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I tried many ways to solve this error (using maven project)

1. I put hibernate.cfg.xml file in src folder then got same error(hibernate.properties does not found)
2. I put hibernate.cfg.xml file in resource folder then got same error(hibernate.properties does not found)
3. I put hibernate.cfg.xml file in webapp/WEB-INF folder then got same error(hibernate.properties does not found)
4. All properties of database i have written in hibernate.cfg.xml is as belows

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
 
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">sql123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create </property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="Employee-hbn.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I got exception is as follows:

```html
May 22, 2018 2:28:38 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.0.Final}
May 22, 2018 2:28:38 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml]
error
```

If you have solution for this then tell me

Thanks in advance....

Comment: you have given "Employee-hbn.xml" for mapping 'hbm' xml resource. Can you check whether the file name is correct or not here. Change file name as 'Employee.hbm.xml' once.  Generally 'hibernate.cfg.xml' file should be place in 'src/main/resources' path

Comment: yeah, file name of "Employee-hbn.xml" is same as i put in hbn mapping and "hibenate.cfg.xml" is also in 'src/main/resources' path....

Comment: Change the file name as "Employee.hbm.xml" and  you also need the supportive jar file for the hibernate like antlr.jar ,hibernate3.jar, and commons jars. etc.. Please check the required jar's once

Comment: Please maintain the path like "com/Test/sampleproject/yourhbmfilename.hbm.xml" in mapping

Comment: Please, add the stack trace of the error. Where do you have that error?

Comment: Here is the error    May 22, 2018 2:28:38 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.0.Final}
May 22, 2018 2:28:38 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml]
error

Comment: Please, add the error in the question. Also keep in mind that it is not an error `INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found`. This is just a warning.

Comment: I have added.................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml]
>   error

This means that Hibernate tries to find `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the

`/src/main/java/hibernate.cfg.xml`.

This is an incorrect path.

You should:

1. Put `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the `resources` folder.
2. Use `Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure()` for configuration.
3. Refresh project and check that `hibernate.cfg.xml` resides in the root of the `build` folder.

Some explanations:

`Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure()`

means the same as

`Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");`

And this line tells Hibernate to locate `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the root of the class path. For example, if you build a `jar` this file should be in the root of the `jar`.

For a `war` the root of the class path is `WEB-INF/classes`.

When you put files in the `resources` folder Maven puts all content of the `resources` folder to the root of the class path (to the root of `jar`, or to the ). So you will not have the `resources` folder in the `jar`, just content of it.

Your IDE do the same when you refresh the project.

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernate.cfg.xml needs to be visible in the classpath.

For a web placing it in WEB-INF/classes will probably work.

For a maven project which is not web you can use /src/main/resources/ which is the default maven resources folder (or use a different one if you have switched it).

Also in your pom.xml you need to have a dependency to hibernate-core